# HTTP Header Angular 6

Tags: angular5, angular, angular-routing

Добрый день подскажите как правильно передать header в angular6

```
 let headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers = headers.set('h1', 'v1');

return this.http.get<any[]>('http://mysite.com/api/method', {headers});
```

при этом header передается не так как ожидалось
Access-Control-Request-Headers: h1 
т.е передается только header но и записывается он не как отдельный, а как value у Access-Control-Request-Headers[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: причем если добавлять header как в коде выше, то меняется method с GET на OPTIONS

Answer (score 1):

Он не меняется, а так сказать предваряется. Потому что у вас изначально скрипт загрузился с одного домена (localhost:4200), а запрос отправляет к другому (mysite.com...). Это называется CORS, и избавиться от этого запроса нельзя, это встроенный механизм современных браузеров. Подробнее про него почитать можно например тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Что касается заголовков, то с виду все правильно, только по моему не `get(url, headers)` а `get(url, { headers: headers })` поскольку второй аргумент это объект у которого заголовки это одно из возможных полей.

Comment: Удивительная особенность русского сегмента stackoverflow, зайти и молча нажать "минус". Зачем что-то объяснять, комментировать, давать свой единственно правильный ответ, тратить свое божественное время... Спасибо, очень мотивирует еще полгода сюда не заходить.

Comment: Ну можно начать с того что ваш ответ не совсем верен. Во первых да вы правы отчасти ошибка была из-за того что некорректно был настроен proxy.config. Во вторых в представленном коде была допущена глупая ошибка т.к. новый заголовок должен добавляться через метод .append, а не .set.  По поводу второго аргумента если я не ошибаюсь то название параметра нужно указывать только в том случае если мы передаем вручную описываем второй аргумент, а в примере мы передаем  объект типа header так же как и можем передать объект params если заранее объявим его. Ну а в третьих минус был не от меня.

Comment: Справедливости ради должен отметить что ради интереса перепроверил и  изменил append на set и все корректно сработало так что ошибка была только в конфигурации proxy